# How do I compare two datetime intervals in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to compare the interval of two datetimes to see if the interval is in the past, in the future or now.

```
$current_time = new DateTime();
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2018-03-17 18:25:00'); 
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-03-17 20:00:00');

if($current_time >= $datetime1 && $current_time <= $datetime2){
   // now
} elseif($current_time >= $datetime1){
   // past
} elseif($current_time <= $datetime1){
   // future
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry, just realised posting my whole real code would make it easier for everyone.

The example above does work but it doesnt work when I loop thru the db using more than one interval from there

```
function interval(){ 

    ....

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $start_time = $row['start_time'];
      $end_time = $row['end_time'];

      $now = new DateTime();
      $datetime1 = new DateTime($start_time);
      $datetime2 = new DateTime($end_time);

        if($now >= $datetime1 && $now <= $datetime2){
          // now
        }elseif($now < $datetime1 && $now < $datetime2){
          // past
        }elseif($now > $datetime1 && $now > $datetime2){
          // future
        }else{
          // fail?
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`date` returns a string.  If you actually want to use a real `DateTime` object, then you need to do something like:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$other = new DateTime('2018-03-18 17:45:00'); //note: example made off the top of my head... value presented may not work

if ($now < $other) {
    //do something
}
```

More information can, as always, be found in the PHP manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @scriptingtime What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As your dates are already string just compare them like that

```
$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$datetime1 = '2018-03-17 18:25:00'; 
$datetime2 = '2018-03-17 20:00:00';

if($current_time >= $datetime1 && $current_time <= $datetime2){
   // now
} elseif($current_time >= $datetime1){
   // past
} elseif($current_time <= $datetime1){
   // future
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand why your code isn't working as intended?
Below is how I would approach the question.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$current_time = new DateTime();
$compareWith = new DateTime('2018-03-16 18:25:00');


if ($current_time >= $compareWith) {
    //whatever your heart desires
}
else{
    //whatever your heart desires
}
```

Comment: what happens that is unexpected when you call interval()? also, if we can assume that end time is always greater than start time, you can simplify the conditionals.